# Creating Direct2D PathGeometry from XAML format

Tags: 2d, directx11, wpf, vector-art, direct2d

Is it possible to create a Direct2D PathGeometry object from a XAML string (or from any other vector format) or do I have to create such a parser myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I wasn't able to find if a straight conversion from a Xaml string to a Direct2D Geometry object exists. I used this [SE answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115388/parsing-svg-path-elements-with-c-sharp-are-there-libraries-out-there-to-do-t) to build my own version. It works by [parsing](https://github.com/AvengerDr/Odyssey/blob/master/Source/Odyssey.Renderer2D/UserInterface/Style/VectorArtParser.cs) the markup and [converting](https://github.com/AvengerDr/Odyssey/blob/4af8b8ead35d911f07a7eb3ef6aac86e3448909b/Source/Odyssey.Renderer2D/Graphics/Drawing/FigureParser.cs) the resulting instructions to GeometrySink commands.